# How to repeat a task every 25hours in tasker

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, task, tasker

I want to create a profile in tasker which repeats a task every 25 hours. I am unable to do it please help me if you can. I tried to create a time profile but it doesn't allow me to repeat every 25 hours.

Comment: Hello Deathrays, The StackOverflow community requests that you provide (at least) a minimal example of the work you've done so far in this process. Could you share some of the code you've already written? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The "Time" profile in Tasker only allows the "Every" parameter to be 1-12 hours, so there is no easy way to do this. As a workaround you could set a profile to every hour, then count a variable up until it's set at 25, then set the variable again to 0 and run your task.

As a side note: for Tasker you will receive more help on reddit, which is according to the Tasker Site the official place for Forum/Support and where the developer is also active.